# How to communicate between android application and pic micro controller via internet?

Tags: php, android

I am trying to send data from android app to pic micro controller and back via internet. I have already done via WIFI. Due to distance issue need communication over internet.
Now am using a web server in between and i can communicate with server using url. and can get immediet response from php code. But i dont know how can i send this data getting from phone to micro controller and response from here want to send to phone.

Comment: Use GSM Modem Instead.

Comment: can i communicate by using a web server in between?

Comment: Yes you can using GPRS of GSM Modem.

Comment: i think this is same as i said.... am using home wifi...

Comment: Hey GSM modem have SIM card slot so, it is working remotely no need to be in wifi range

Comment: i can send data (name:a) to my web server page, and will get a response(name:a_response). I need to send the data 'a' from server to micro controller and a_response want to be this.... but when i try to send this data to micro controller code will not work....Is there any  sample code or libraries or any reference to do this?

Comment: in phone i have internet so i can directly send to web server, and there is wifi where my device placed.... then why gsm modem

Comment: i used GSm modem already in a project, there is no phone and wifi.... Here the problem is not a medium

Comment: As per your question if you don't want to be in wifi range then you can use GSM Modem.